# How to count the number of characters between two characters in a string

Tags: ruby, string

This is the question's prompt:

> Write a method that takes a string and returns `true` if the letter
>       `"z"` appears within three letters after an `"a"`. You may assume
>       that the string contains only lowercase letters.

I'm trying to use the ternary operator, and want to include the `match` or `count` methods. Any idea on how I can find the number of characters between `"a"` and `"z"` or the simplest way to solve this?

```
def nearby_az(string)
  string.count <= 3 ? true : false
end
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `match` and `count`?

Comment: Your current code has nothing to do with `'a'` or `'z'`.

Comment: I know, I had no idea how to begin :| No need for match or count, I was just thinking that I might be able to use them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regex would be a good way to solve this problem.

You can use [online regex testers](https://regex101.com/) to experiment with different regexes, inputs and outputs.

The first solution that comes to my mind is to come up with a pattern for each possible correct input:

- az
- a[a-z]z
- a[a-z][a-z]z

Which means:

- Match the string "az"
- Match a string with "a" and then a character from "a" to "z" and then a "z" character
- Match a string with an "a" and then 2 characters from "a" to "z" and then a "z"

and then combine them with the 'or' operator (|)

- az|a[a-z]z|a[a-z][a-z]z

Which means match on all three of those conditions.

[A link to this example is here](https://regex101.com/r/rC2gU5/1).

Doing it this way is a bit verbose so it can be improved by expressing this in a more compact way:

- a[a-z]{0,2}z

This means:

- Match an "a" then match a character from "a" to "z" 0, 1 or 2 times and then match a "z"

[A link to this example is here](https://regex101.com/r/rC2gU5/2)

You use the method on ruby strings called match which takes in a regex object and then check the boolean return value.

Edit:

The ruby code would look something like this:

```
def nearby_az(string)
  return string.match(/a[a-z]{0,2}z/) != nil
end
```

string.match() returns an object that you can query to get information about the match. If there is no match, string.match() will return nil.

Comment: Wow this is very informative, thank you! 
Could the code look something like this?
`string.match(/a[a-z]{0,2}z/) ? true : false`

Comment: Edited my post to explain ruby side of it.

Comment: I like how this answer explains in increments.  Nicely done.  By the way, a terser form of the function is possible: `string =~ /a[a-z]{0,2}z/`

Comment: What if `string = 'a3z'`? You could replace `[a-z]` with `.`, but then your answer (aside from the discussion) would be the same as @sawa's.

Answer (score 5):

```
!!("fjeioaeiz" =~ /a.{,2}z/) #=> true
!!("fjeioaz" =~ /a.{,2}z/) #=> true
!!("fjeioasbdz" =~ /a.{,2}z/) #=> false
```

Comment: `/(?<=a)(.{,2})(?=z)/` gives more accurate match :)

Comment: @mudasobwa As I understand, extracting a match is not the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Look, Ma! No regex!

```
def a_upto_4_z(str)
   str.each_char.with_index.any? { |c,i| c == ?a && str[i+1,3].include?(?z) }
end

a_upto_4_z "rvaxxzo"  #=> true 
a_upto_4_z "rvaxxxzo" #=> false 
a_upto_4_z "rvaxzo"   #=> true 
a_upto_4_z "rvazo"    #=> true 
a_upto_4_z "rvzao"    #=> false
```

**Edit**: @Stefan makes a good point. Let's do it this way:

```
def mind_the_gap(str, max_gap=2)
  gap = max_gap + 1 # or larger
  str.each_char do |c|
    case c
    when ?z
      return true if gap <= max_gap
    when ?a
      gap = 0
    else
      gap += 1
    end
  end
  false
end

mind_the_gap "rvaxxzo"  #=> true 
mind_the_gap "rvaxxxzo" #=> false 
mind_the_gap "rvaxzo"   #=> true 
mind_the_gap "rvazo"    #=> true 
mind_the_gap "rvzao"    #=> false
```

Note it is not necessary to increment `gap` when `c == ?z` and `gap > max_gap`.

Comment: +1 for a no-rexgex alternative, but you're processing parts of the string multiple times due to `str[i+1,3].include?`. It should be enough, to check each character once.